# Android custom actionbar is shown only after default

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created new Android project with only 1 activity. I have created custom view for ActionBar. But when I launch the app for 1-2 seconds I see blank screen and default black Actionbar with app name on it. Only after second when content is loaded my action bar is shown.

How to remove this default action bar showing on start? Code is simple:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

    ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    supportActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    supportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    supportActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    supportActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

Comment: I need AppCompat theme

Comment: please post your manifest so that I can come up with exact solution.bcoz In appplication also you can set a theme

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity:**

```
  private ActionBar actionabar;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

actionabar = getActionBar();
actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

}
```

**In Manifest:**

Inside `activity` element you have to add these theme

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

**For Eg:**

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```